# Render JSON value as a text besides a key Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nlp

I have a document that is the output of a list of lists with dictionaries inside:

```
[{'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.99999213, 'word': 'DNA', 'start': 0, 'end': 3}, {'entity_group': 'metaphoric', 'score': 0.9768174, 'word': 'loop', 'start': 4, 'end': 8}, {'entity_group': 'literal', 'score': 0.9039155, 'word': 'ing,', 'start': 8, 'end': 12}]
```

I want to group the "literal" in order to get the text only, so that it becomes

> DNA {metaphoric:loop}ing

so leave the metaphoric as it is. I tried with this code below but it says string indices must be integers, and I'm not actually able to get the solution as I wish.

```
with open(r'MYFILE.txt', 'r') as res:
  texty = res.read()
  for group in texty[::-1]:
      ent = group["entity_group"]
      if ent != 'literal': 
      text2 = replace_at(ent, group['end'], group['end'], text)
print(text2)
```

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for group in texty[::-1]:`, what do you think this means? What do you think `group` will be, each time through the loop? Did you try to check that? What do you want it to be, instead? Also: if you are aware that the file is JSON, why not read and parse it as JSON?

Comment: I put what I want it to be in the question. Also, it's a list containing JSON so I'm not really sure how to do that

Comment: No; you wrote what you want the final output to be. I can't make any sense out of "group the "literal" in order to get the text only", nor can I see how that relates to the final output. But more importantly, I can't understand the **process you want the code to follow** in order to get that output. "Also, it's a list containing JSON" No, it isn't. It is **a string**. `with open(r'MYFILE.txt', 'r') as res:` means to open the file **to read text from it**, and `texty = res.read()` will read the entire thing **as text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desire output is unclear so I can only guess what I think you wanted until you update your question.

```
import json

with open ('MYFILE.txt') as f:
    texty = json.load (f)

for group in texty:
    if 'literal' not in group ['entity_group']:
        print ('DNA {%s:%s}ing' % (group ['entity_group'], group ['word']))
```

Output:

```
DNA {metaphoric:loop}ing
```